# Is there an equivalent to Godel's theorem that looks like "This statement is provable."?

Tags: incompleteness, paradoxes

I've been thinking about Godel's thoerem and the liar's paradox.  The liar's paradox, when flipped around, stops being a paradox and becomes valid logically whether the statement is true or not. "This statement is true" works if true or false.  I was wondering how the Godel argument would work if it was also flipped.  Perhaps it would read like "this statement is provable."  I don't understand the logic language he used in his proof, so I have to think about these things in normal language, but I was hoping somebody could highlight what that might look like and what the interpretation would be.

Comment: You can certainly write such a statement using Gödel, but it might be decidable, so it depends on what you mean by “works.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In fact it will **always** be decidable - this is [Lob's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem). (See the linked duplicate question for further details about exactly what's needed to be confident about this.)

Comment: To the OP, this is a great question but it is a duplicate.